# HTTP 503 error accessing Sharepoint excelservice.asmx through SOAP

Tags: sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2010, http-status-code-503

I work for The Smeal College of Business at Penn State. I am doing a project for the Supply chain program and I am creating an excel workbook in Sharepoint that uses a lot of UDF's.  I have no problem accessing the workbook or using other UDF's, but when I try to use OpenWorkbookForEditing() I get the following stack trace:

System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 503: Service Unavailable.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at ClassName.ExcelWebService.ExcelService.OpenWorkbookForEditing(String workbookPath, String uiCultureName, String dataCultureName, Status[]& status)
   at ClassName.ClassNameFunctions.testWriteCell()

Additionally, I've tried to access excelservice.asmx through PHP SOAP and have not received a response.  Each attempt to connect to this service provides a 503 error in the IIS logs similar to the following:

2012-08-06 15:14:58 xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxxxxx POST /_vti_bin/excelservice.asmx - 80 - xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxxxxx Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.5456) 503 0 0 59

I've tried changing most of the settings in Sharepoint Central Administration, as well as some of the setting in IIS.  Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?  Thanks.

I'm running a Sharepoint 2010 server on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Can take a look at this article maybe it will help.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513104.aspx

The solution that is suggested here is to just restart.  If this is a dev machine that shouldn't be a big deal.

Also make sure that no application pools have stopped as this could make the service unavailable.

Comment: Josh thanks for your reply.  I've found this page before and tried this solution.  The server has been restarted multiple times, and while occasionally the service has become stopped through my testing, I know this is not the main issue.